# Finding substring using regular exp

Tags: java, regex

I have a string

```
abc.xyz.qweweer.cccc
```

This is actually going to be a Java package name.

I am trying to find out the last string using reg exp, in the above example `cccc` is the last String.

Basically I am trying to find out the class name from the package string.

How to find out through Java

Comment: I already have a logic, 1) find the last index of '.' 2) Do substring index,length of package name. Now i am just trying out if it is possible thru regexp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a string `pkg = "abc.xyz.qweweer.cccc"` you can solve it like this:

- Using `indexOf`:

  ```
  int index = pkg.lastIndexOf('.');
  String lastPart = index == -1 ? pkg : pkg.substring(index + 1);
  ```
- Using regular expressions with `Matcher`:

  ```
  Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^.]*$").matcher(pkg);
  String lastPart = m.find() ? m.group() : null;
  ```
- Using `split` (variation of RMT's answer):

  ```
  String[] names = pkg.split("\\.");
  String lastPart = names[names.length - 1];
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just split on the "."

```
String[] names = packageName.split(".");
String className = names[names.length-1];
```

Comment: i just edited my answer because i made a mistake, the split() method actually uses regex.  public String[] split(String regex)

Answer (score 0):

### Alt1 - Extract desired

```
String packageName = ...
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+$").matcher(packageName);
if (m.find()) {
    m.group(); // your match
}
```

### Alt2 - Remove undesired

You could also try the somewhat less verbose approach:

```
String result = packageName.replaceAll(".*\\.", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache StringUtils [substringAfterLast](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringAfterLast%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for this.

```
StringUtils.substringAfterLast("abc.xyz.qweweer.cccc", ".")
```

Regex is not required for this.

Comment: Unless he's already using commons, I wouldn't encourage him to include a full blown library in his application, to make a 2-liner into a 1-liner.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to use regex? You could do a `str.substring (str.lastIndexOf (".") + 1)` to get the classname.

Comment: Requires a `"."` to be present in the package name (which is not true for package names in general).